android jacoco gradle managed devices
I now have gradle managed devices set up for running my tests.   They work nicely for the tests.   I'd like to get jacoco to give me code coverage for those tests.
That seems to work rather badly.  BTW, this is a library module (I think the app module actually works).   I'm running this from the command line.   It fails saying there are no connected devices, then proceeds to start up the gradle managed device, and runs all the tests run cleanly.  It seems like a sequencing issue.
createDebugCoverageReport is dependent on connectedDebugAndroidTest.  I like to make it dependent on my gradle manage device test (in my case pixel2DebugAndroidTest).
Are there any options for jacoco to work with gradle managed devices?
